Why Is S3 Traffic Routing Through NAT Gateway Despite S3 Gateway Endpoint?
Despite configuring both S3 Gateway and ECR Interface Endpoints in my AWS VPC to reduce NAT Gateway costs. I’m still seeing large amounts of traffic from S3 public IP addresses going through the NAT Gateway.
My setup is:

VPC: Private VPC in eu-west-2 region.
S3 Gateway Endpoint: Configured for S3 (vpce-xxxxxxx).
ECR API and DKR Endpoints: Configured and added to route tables.
NAT Gateway: Set up for outbound traffic that’s not S3-related.

The private route table has routes for:

S3 Traffic: Using the prefix list (pl-xxxxxx) to the S3 Gateway Endpoint.
0.0.0.0/0 Route: Pointing to the NAT Gateway for all other traffic.

The problem is traffic from S3 IP addresses (e.g., 52.xx.xx.xx) to ECS tasks in the VPC (private IP addresses) is still going through the NAT Gateway, causing high traffic costs.
From VPC Flow Logs, I’ve noticed consistent large transfers (~3 GB) from S3 IP addresses to ECS tasks, which might be ECR image pulls.
I'm trying to find out:

Why is S3 traffic being routed through the NAT Gateway despite having the S3 Gateway Endpoint?
Could the ECS tasks be using global S3 endpoints rather than regional ones?
How can I ensure all S3 and ECR traffic uses the VPC Endpoints and bypasses the NAT Gateway?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Are DNS hostnames and DNS resolution both enabled for your VPC?

@jarmod yes, they are.

@DannyS Please check S3 VPC Endpoint Policy whether it has any restrictions on S3 resources!!.
